# Combinatoric Questions with Matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

We randomly choose (with repetition) $2n^2$ numbers from the set {$1,2,...,k$}.

Than, we randomly arrange the $2n^2$ chosen numbers in a $n$ x $2n$ matrix.

How much different Matrices exists, such that in each Matrix, every row is different.

---

My attempt:

First, look at Row $1$, there are $k^{2n}$ options for that row.

For Row $2$, we than have $k^{2n-1}$ options, and so on until we reach Row $n$, which has $k^n$ options.

So in total, we have $\prod_{i=0}^n k^{2n-i}$

Is that correct?

Thanks!